# Яке походження слово «плахта»?

Tags: етимологія

У творах багатьох українських письменників вживається слово «плахта».

> "Його позир слідкував за нею, доки манячила через рідке гілля її червона запаска та квітчаста плахта." (З тв. Івана Нечуя-Левицького).

Вікіпедія, етимологічний словник подають його лексичне значення:

> «Жіночий одяг замість спідниці; картата декоративна тканина; покривало або килим з такої тканини…» — Етимологічний словник української мови: В 7 т.

Щодо походження назви в словниках не знайшла точного визначення, наводяться лише паралелі співзвучних слів у різних мовах. Допоможіть, друзі, визначити походження цього слова.

Answer (score 3):

У тому ж таки Етимологічному словнику української мови: В 7 т. пише:

> **Старослов’янське** **плахъта** - парусина, полотно.
>
> **Праслов’янське** **plaxъta** - полотно, простирадло, покривало, навіс.
>
> Очевидно, похідне утворення від **plaxa**, "**плаха**" (порівняйте українське
>   "**плаха**" - складова частина **невода**, полотнище невода; верхня частина
>   свинячої туші - шар сала.)

Отже, має походження зі старослов’янської і праслов’янської мов.

[image]
[image]